# Updating attributes on dynamically created lightning components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

Say I have a Component that acts as a container and on init I dynamically create a custom component.  The custom component has 2 attributes, "name" and "message".

Container Component:

```
<!-- Container Component -->
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    {!v.basicInfo}
    <ui:button press="{!c.setChildAttribute}">Pass Attribute</ui:button>
</aura:component >
```

And its controller:

```
({
    init: function(cmp){
        console.log('cmp -> ' + cmp);
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:SegmentBasicInfo",
            {
                "name" : "testName",
                "message" : "test message"
             },
            function(basicInfo){
                cmp.set("v.basicInfo", basicInfo);
        }
      )
    },
    setChildAttribute : function (cmp){
        var basicInfo = cmp.get("v.basicInfo");
        basicInfo.name = "newTest";
        basicInfo.message = "new Test Message";
        cmp.set('v.basicInfo', basicInfo);
    }
})
```

Inner Component:

```
<!-- Inner Component -->
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="name" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
    {!v.name} says {!v.message}!
<aura:component >
```

The dynamic component is successfully created but the button doesn't update the attributes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please use below link for best ans. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80803/dynamically-created-lightning-components-and-attributes/165181#165181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set component attributes with dot notation like that. Assuming v.basicInfo is of type Aura.Component, try instead:

```
setChildAttribute : function (cmp){
    var basicInfo = cmp.get("v.basicInfo");
    basicInfo.set("v.name", "newTest");
    basicInfo.set("v.message", "new Test Message");
}
```

Comment: nice! One small change: `basicInfo.set("v.name", "newTest");` and it works! if you'll update your response i'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Oops you're right! I keep forgetting about that pesky `v` :)